# Want to access S3 using EC2 instance profile from a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Suppose you have 2 accounts (A,B).

In account A, you have created an S3 bucket.

In account B you have created an EC2 instance.

How can you access the S3 bucket in account A from the EC2 instance in Account B?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: Thank you for youe help. But the role is attached to user not to ec2 instance

Comment: You mentioned "instance profile" which is a container for an IAM role that's passed to the EC2 instance when launched. That's the 'proper' way to provide credentials to an EC2 instance. That aside, you can set up cross-account access to account A's bucket from IAM credentials in account B. See the earlier link or https://pete.wtf/2012/02/02/how-to-enable-cross-account-aws-access-with-iam-users/.

Answer (score 3):

So, the situation is:

- Account A has Amazon S3 **Bucket A**
- Account B has an Amazon EC2 **Instance B**
- You want to **access Bucket A from Instance B**

Best practice is to assign credentials to an Amazon EC2 instance by **associating an IAM Role with the EC2 instance**. Then, any application running on the instance has automatic access to these credentials.

However, in this situation there's one additional requirement because Account B cannot allocate permission to access resources in Account A. Therefore, the required steps are:

- Create an **IAM Role** in Account B and associate it with Instance B (normal)
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to Bucket A that grants access (eg `GetObject`) to the role in Account B

Here is a sample bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "CrossAccountAccess",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AccessFromRole",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/role-in-account-b"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy is permitting the role in Account B (`Principal`) to access the bucket in Account A (`Resource`).

This way, any EC2 instance in Account B launched with the specified Role will be permitted to `GetObject` from Bucket A.

Comment: Okay so i have to attach this bucket policy to my bucket . but what policy should i include in role of account b which attached to instance b?

Comment: Role B does not need any permissions. In fact, it *cannot* grant permissions for resources in a difference account. It is merely acting as a means of providing credentials to Instance B and provides an ARN (Amazon Resource Name) so that the Bucket Policy on Bucket A can refer to the Role. Think of it like this: I tell the security guard (Mr A) at the front door of a building to let Mrs B enter the building, and the guard lets her in. Mrs B does not have a key to the building. Rather, the building guard (Mr A) granted her access. All Mrs B needed was an ID to show who she was.